# RHEL Error message mounting luks crypted filesystem at boot

Tags: linux, filesystems, dm-crypt

I am configuring a luks crypted file system to be mounted at boot time using RHEL 6.5

I did all the configuration from command line and tt worked but printed an error message after asking for password

```
/crypted is password protected:*********
modprobe: FATAL: Error inserting padlock_sha (/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/crypto/padlock-sha.ko): No such device
```

I did some research and found some old RedHat ticket regarding this, one of the ticket says this is because that module is only for Via chips.

If I configured encrypted file system via anaconda and there is no such error message so I believe there is something I missed or did not do right.

Any idea ?

here is what I did

```
echo "modprobe dm_crypt" > /etc/sysconfig/modules/load_dm_crypt.modules
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/vg01/lv_crypt
cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/vg01/lv_crypt
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/vg01/lv_crypt lv_crypt
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/lv_crypt

cat /etc/crypttab
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/crypttab 
lv_crypt UUID=5fd651df-f946-40ab-a07b-47cd63207f3f none
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/fstab | grep lv_crypt
/dev/mapper/lv_crypt    /crypted        ext4    defaults        1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

That kernel module is intended to support specific cryptographic hardware, [VIA PadLock](http://www.via.com.tw/en/initiatives/padlock/hardware.jsp). Loading the module will fail when a VIA CPU with those crypto extentions isn't present.

The question is why loading that module is attempted in the first place. Do you have a VIA cpu? Because on my system without one the non-hardware accelerated module `sha256_generic` gets loaded for my LUKS partition.

Did you follow the Red Hat [manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/Disk_Encryption_Guide.html) to set up LUKS and is `/etc/crypttab` configured?

Comment: Added my commands, maybe the way I load modules is not correct?